# How to display pending posts on the homepage only for editors

Tags: loop, post-status

I'm working on a project where editors need to see the pending posts on the homepage to improve them before publish.

Maybe there is something to do with the loop in this way:

If editors logged:

```
if ( current_user_can('edit_post') ) {
    display the pending posts
}
```

The args to display publish and pending posts:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish, pending' );
```

The completed loop:

```
<?php
if ( current_user_can('edit_post') ) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish, pending' );
} else {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
}
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

…the content here...

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

It work for me.

Do you think this is correct?

Maybe the code can be improved.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would filter `pre_get_posts`.

```
function allow_pending_posts_wpse_103938($qry) {
  if (!is_admin() && current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
    $qry->set('post_status', array('publish','pending'));
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','allow_pending_posts_wpse_103938');
```

That should show `pending` posts to your editors for all of your queries on the front end. You can, of course, restrict is more if you'd like.

I'd add some code to mark the pending posts so your editors know at a glance what is pending.

Comment: I reiterate, that will effect ___all___ queries on the front end. Be aware.